# Data masking and plotting issues xarray/rioxarray | geojson -> geoviews

Tags: geojson, geopandas, netcdf, rioxarray, holoviews

I'm loading a NetCDF file (ERA5 surface temperatures), then I mask the data using country shapes, and finally generate a plot using geoviews. For the unmasked data everything works as intended. As soon as I clip using rioxarray, half the globe goes missing. In detail:

```
# Read all relevant data:
data0 = xr.open_dataset("./data/COPERNICUS/adaptor.mars.internal-1621870453.0792851-5880-10-bd60c7b4-8e84-4d2a-acfb-d2cc442d24e1.nc")
sf = geopandas.read_file("./data/NATURAL_EARTH/ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp")

# Filter and set CRS:
dataslice = data0.load().where((data0.time.dt.strftime("%Y") == "2020") & (data0.expver == 1)
                                  , drop=True).sum("expver").resample({"time": "Y"}).mean()
dataslice.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="longitude", y_dim="latitude", inplace=True)
dataslice.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)
```

Plotting this with geoviews looks ok:

```
dataset = gv.Dataset(dataslice, ['longitude', 'latitude', 'time'], 't2m')
images = dataset_clipped.to(gv.Image)
images.opts(cmap='viridis', colorbar=True, width=900, height=600, 
            projection=crs.PlateCarree())
```

[image]

Now I want to clip the data using the shapefile and plot the clipped data:

```
clipped = dataslice.rio.clip(sf.geometry, drop=False)
dataset_clipped = gv.Dataset(clipped, ['longitude', 'latitude', 'time'], 't2m')
images_clipped = dataset_clipped.to(gv.Image)
images_clipped.opts(cmap='viridis', colorbar=True, width=900, height=600, 
                    projection=crs.PlateCarree())
```

While the data is clipped by the landmass as intended, all of the Western hemisphere is gone as well.

[image]

Remarks:

- This does not depend on the `projection` parameter of geoviews.
- Both the gridded data and the shapefile have CRS EPSG:4326.
- The Shapefile is complete:

[image]

**Questions:**

- What is going wrong?
- Why do we need to set the CRS anyway? Both the xarray and the geojsons are just tuples (lat,lon,value) and (lat,lon), respectively. Yet `dataslice.rio.clip` raises a MissingCRS exception if `dataslice.rio.write_crs` is skipped.

Comment: Given that the clipping boundary appears to go through Greenwich, England (0 deg meridian), this looks like an issue with coordinates wrapping around at 0.  You may be able to avoid it by adding 360 to the coordinates at some step, but if you can make a reproducible test case depending on open datasets then please file an issue on GeoViews so we can figure out where this is happening.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment but as it turns out it's not geoviews related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to adjust the longitude values to -180,180 range from 0-360. See: [Clip global data by polygon using rioxarray fails (off by 180 longitude)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357246/clip-global-data-by-polygon-using-rioxarray-fails-off-by-180-longitude)

```py
ds = ds.assign_coords(x=(((ds.x + 180) % 360) - 180)).sortby('x')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for: Known problem, easy fix.