# How does one convert a raster from 0 to 360 to -180 to 180 using rasterio

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I'm curious if there is a way to reproject a raster to have 0 as the center longitude rather than 180. I am trying to convert [this raster](https://judson-stack-exchange.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/CFSv2_v2.tif). I've been able to do this in gdal, but I'd like the solution to be in rasterio as it's more pythonic and I also don't think you're supposed to mix the two within one script. I've tried a couple different ways, but I believe the following to be the closest:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import reproject


def change_center_long_from_180_to_0(input_fp, output_fp):
    with rasterio.open(input_fp) as src:
        kwargs = src.meta.copy()
        kwargs.update({'CENTER_LONG': 0, 'SOURCE_EXTRA':1000})
        with rasterio.open(output_fp, 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            for i in range(1, src.count + 1):
                reproject(
                    source=rasterio.band(src, i),
                    destination=rasterio.band(dst, i),
                    src_transform=src.transform,
                    src_crs=src.crs)

    return
```

However, this isn't doing anything to the raster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try rioxarray:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/357810

```py
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(input_fp)
rds = rds.assign_coords(x=(((rds.x + 180) % 360) - 180)).sortby('x')
rds.rio.to_raster(output_fp)
```

Comment: Very easy method and much faster than the "R" alternative. Got to change ds.x to rds.x for this to work though.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked & thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with 0-360 data and the easiest method that I have found is in R using rotate from the raster library. I just transformed a geoid file from the NGS that was in 0-360 to 0 centered at Greenwich. See below with function calls and dumps of the CRS info.
Note:

- the shift worked despite the warning thrown in R
- there are other output types than .asc which generated a larger file than the .bin

'''

```
    library(raster)
    > dir()[2]
    [1] "g2012bu0.bin"
    > r<-raster(dir()[2])
    > r
    class      : RasterLayer 
    dimensions : 2041, 4201, 8574241  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
    resolution : 0.01666667, 0.01666667  (x, y)
    extent     : 229.9917, 300.0083, 23.99167, 58.00833  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
    ymax)
    crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs 
    source     : g2012bu0.bin 
    names      : g2012bu0 

    > r2<-rotate(r)
    Warning message:
    In .local(x, ...) :
      this does not look like an appropriate object for this function
    
    > r2
    class      : RasterLayer 
    dimensions : 2041, 4201, 8574241  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
    resolution : 0.01666667, 0.01666667  (x, y)
    extent     : -130.0083, -59.99167, 23.99167, 58.00833  (xmin, xmax, ymin, 
    ymax)
    crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +no_defs 
    source     : g2012bu0.bin 
    names      : g2012bu0 
    > writeRaster(r2,'g2012bu0.asc')
    
    '''
```